# Upgrading from Codeigniter 1.7.3 to 2.2.0 - Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've updated everything as its requested to update my version to the latest one.
However in my `view` files I am receiving some errors and I dont get it why: Example this below:

```
<a href="#" class="teams_button_2">'.($relations[$team->teams_id]?$relation_names[$relations[$team->teams_id]]:'Neutral').'</a>
```

I get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: relations

Filename: pages/teams.php

Line Number: 48
```

**It worked perfectly before but not anymore. I got some others similiar like that. What may cause it?**

UPDATE: the controller for that:

```
function view()
  {


$data['player'] = $this->user->info( $this->user->id() );
$data['motors_count'] = $this->user->count_motors( $this->user->id() );

$data['menu_active']['teams'] = ' active';

$data['teams'] = $this->db->order_by( 'team_points', 'desc' )->get( 'teams' )->result();

if ( $this->user->team_id() )
{
    $relations = $this->db->where( 'teams_relations_teams_id', $this->user->team_id() )->get( 'teams_relations' )->result();
}

$requests = $this->db->where( 'teams_join_requests_user_id', $this->user->id() )->get( 'teams_join_requests' )->result();
$data['requests'] = array();


if ( $relations )
    foreach ( $relations as $relation )
        $data['relations'][$relation->teams_relations_second_teams_id] = $relation->teams_relations_type;

if ( $requests )
    foreach ( $requests as $request )
        $data['requests'][] = $request->teams_join_requests_teams_id;

$this->load->view( 'logged/includes/header.php', $data );
$this->load->view( 'logged/pages/teams.php' );
$this->load->view( 'logged/includes/footer.php' );

}
```

Comment: try `var_dump($data['relations'])` check if its set or not. you didn't passed `$data` to `teams.php view` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

in your Controller $relations is optional - you have it wrapped in an IF -  but then in your View its not optional.

either check for $relations in your controller -- and if there is no $relations -- then call a view which does not use it. OR check for $relations in your view file.

So here is an issue --

```
$relations = $this->db->where( 'teams_relations_teams_id', $this->user->team_id() )->get( 'teams_relations' )->result();
```

but what happens if you don't get any results back? to check you could write more IF/ELSE code in that method but then it starts turning to Pasta Indented. So this where you would refactor, put that database interaction into a Model, and then have the controller only check if something came back from the database.

also i didn't know so i just tested it - but if you pass $data to only the first load view file (like you are doing), $data will automatically get passed to the other load view files.